# C: resize an array WITHOUT realloc()

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I need to re-size a malloc'd C array.  However, I'm not supposed to use `realloc()` (it's for an assignment).  The below code keeps throwing `double free or corruption (out)`  More specifically, this function seems to do nothing, since the program behaves the same whether I call it or not.  I feel like I'm probably missing something basic.  Can anyone help me out?  Thanks a lot

```
void double_array_size(float *array, int *size) {
  float *temp = NULL;
  int i;
  temp = (float *) malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof(float));

  for (i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
    temp[i] = array[i];
  }

  *size *= 2;

  free(array);
  array = temp;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `void f(int x) {x = 5;} int main() {int i = 7; f(i); printf("%d\n", i); return 0;}` to print?

Comment: @immibis right, but I thought the idea of passing pointers was that it let you change things like that from within another method

Comment: you need passing pointer to pointer like as `float **array`.

Comment: @B1CL0PS You need to post the rest of the code, the main issue is addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32939199/1983495), but I am still curious to see the rest of the code to see how do you expect it to work, and never use `free()` like that, the context where you call `free()` seems wrong and dangerous to me.

Comment: @B1CL0PS  passing pointers allows the function to change the objects pointed to by the pointer.  But `double_array_size()` is also changing the pointer itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like  BLUEPIXY said, pass a double pointer or if you don't want to, better this:

```
float *double_array_size(float *array, int *size) {
  float *temp = NULL;
  int i;
  temp = (float *) malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof(float));

  for (i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
    temp[i] = array[i];
  }   

  *size *= 2;

  free(array);
  return temp;
}
```

and to increase the performance of you code, do not use a `for` loop, use `memcpy` instead:

```
temp = (float *) malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof(float));
memcpy(temp, array, sizeof *array * *size);
```

You should always check the return value of `malloc` and friends. They might return `NULL` and depending on your code, you might have to react to this if you don't want your code to crash.

Another thing: if you are using C only, do not cast `malloc` and I suggest to use `sizeof *var` instead of `sizeof(float)` because you are hardcoding the type. Let's say that you have to change the type of the array. If you hardcore your types, you have to change the types everywhere, otherwise only in the declarations, much less work and fewer errors.

Sometimes you need more or less the same code for different types. Luckily in C++ you have `templates`, in C you have to use Macros, if you don't want to repeat basically the same code over and over, for example:

```
#define DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE(type) \
    type *double_array_size_ ##type (type *array, size_t *size) {\
          type *temp; \
          temp = malloc(*size * 2 * sizeof *array);\
          if(temp == NULL)\
              return NULL;\
          memcpy(temp, array, sizeof *array * *size);\
          *size *= 2;\
          free(array);\
          return temp;\
        }
```

And instead of writing the same code with different types over and over, you can do

```
DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE(int)
DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE(double)
DOUBLE_ARRAY_SIZE(record_t)

void foo()
{
    int *ints = malloc(...);
    record_t *recs = malloc(...);
    ...
    new_ints = double_array_size_int(ints, ints_size);
    new_recs = double_array_size_record_t(recs, recs_size);
    ....
}
```

I know that a lot of people will say *do not use `macros`, they're evil* and they are kind of true, but using them wisely may help you more thank you think. One of the reason you should try to hardcore the datatype as less as possible.

// edit my macro snippet, chux's suggestion with `size_t`

Comment: Minor: `size_t *size` instead of `int *size`.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Answer (score 2):

One problem with this code is that parameters are call-by-value, so you’re changing only the local copy of `array` and leaking memory.  The value in the rest of the program is never updated.  What you want to do is `return` the reallocated array.